# How to force a driver.refresh if webpage takes longer than X seconds to load

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping, selenium-chromedriver

```
try:
                    URL = driver.get('www.google.com')
                    content = driver.page_source
                    soup = bs(content, 'html.parser')
                
except (TimeoutError, AttributeError):
                    print("Site timed out. Refreshing page...")
                    driver.refresh()
```

With my current code, the driver refreshes only after the web page has already timed out. I would like to refresh if the page hasn't loaded within X seconds. Thanks ahead of time.

Answer (score 0):

if your using selenium web driver you can use webDriverWait(driver, 10), this will wait 10 seconds, you can then check if your element is visible in an if statement, if not visible, refresh page...